# find the character "(" in a string in js

Tags: javascript, string, search

I have a string in my JS that may contain the character (M and I need to find their position - but I can't work out how to without throwing an error I guess due to the bracket.

```
const findMTag = "(M"; //I need to search for this but it throws an error
let posMTag = nameJoined.search(findMTag);
console.log("TAG position =  " + posMTag);
```

Comment: Try using [`indexOf()`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/10/f153bbbc218fc169768aa1c02f2e9178e9241e4af8da56289bdca2c0c217/face_recognition-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl)

Comment: Always include the specific error when asking. The actual message should give you a big clue

Comment: Always read the documentation before asking. [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(M/: Unterminated group` is supposed to be pretty clear...

Comment: Thanks - I had searched but I'm very new to this so didn't find what I needed. I understood that my error was to do with the syntax but am not a coder so thought I'd ask - didn't mean to come across as lazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.search accepts a [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as its argument, but you're passing a string to it, so it doesn't work. Take a look at [String.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) for more info.

So your code will look like:

```
const findMTag = /\(M/;
const posMTag = nameJoined.search(findMTag);
console.log("TAG position =  " + posMTag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with indexOf

```
const findMTag = "(M"; //I need to search for this but it throws an error
let posMTag = nameJoined.indexOf(findMTag);
console.log("TAG position =  " + posMTag);
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using indexOf over .search(findMTag); Here to learn